# How to test if every item in a list of type 'int'?

Tags: python, list, int

Say I have a list of numbers. How would I do to check that every item in the list is an int?
I have searched around, but haven't been able to find anything on this.

```
for i in myList:
  result=isinstance(i, int)
  if result == False:
    break
```

would work, but looks very ugly and unpythonic in my opinion.
Is there any better(and more pythonic) way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you need to check this in the first place? Using duck typing is pythonic, checking types for no good reason isn't - do you have a good reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python check if all elements of a list are the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/python-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-the-same-type)

Answer (score 54):

There are a few different ways to do it. For example, if your list includes **only numbers**:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3.25]
>>> all(isinstance(item, int) for item in my_list)
False

>>> other_list = range(3)
>>> all(isinstance(item, int) for item in other_list)
True
>>>
```

Anyways, **this solution doesn't work as expected if your list includes booleans,** as remarked by @merlin:

```
>>> another_list = [1, 2,False]
>>> all(isinstance(item, int) for item in another_list)
True
```

If your list include booleans you should use `type` instead of `isinstance` (it' a little slower, but works as you expect):

```
>>> another_list = [1, 2, False]
>>> all(type(item) is int for item in another_list)
False
>>> last_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> all(type(item) is int for item in last_list)
True
```

Comment: The double parens are optional if the generator expression is the only argument.

Comment: +1 `all` function makes more sense than `any` function. (pretty sure they are equivalent in terms of runtime though)

Comment: To check if each element in that list is an int you can also use this, that seems easier to read to me: `all(type(item) is int for item in my_list)`

Comment: @gerlos is correct, whereas upvoted answer will fail if my_list contains boolean types.  `isinstance(False, int) == True`

Answer (score 9):

The following statement should work. It uses the `any` builtin and a generator expression:

```
any(not isinstance(x, int) for x in l)
```

This will return true if there is a non-int in the list. E.g.:

```
>>> any(not isinstance(x, int) for x in [0,12.])
True
>>> any(not isinstance(x, int) for x in [0,12])
False
```

The `all` builtin could also accomplish the same task, and some might argue it is makes slightly more sense (see [Dragan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234638/dragan-chupacabric)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009589/how-to-test-if-every-item-in-a-list-of-type-int/6009630#6009630))

```
all(isinstance(x,int) for x in l)
```

Comment: I would like to know which 'al'l or 'any' is better to use. When 'any' reaches an object that matches it stops to iterate or it continues till the very end? Because 'all' for sure iterates all the elements but if any doesn't. For me, it's better to use 'any'

Answer (score 2):

One approach would not be to test, but to insist. This means your program can handle a broader range of inputs intelligently -- it won't fail if someone passes it a float instead.

```
int_list = [int(x) for x in int_list]
```

or (in-place):

```
for i, n in enumerate(int_list):
    int_list[i] = int(n)
```

If something can't be converted, it will throw an exception, which you can then catch if you care to.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3]

In [2]: all(type(item)==int for item in a)
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Found myself with the same question but under a different situation: If the "integers" in your list are represented as strings (e.g., as was the case for me after using 'line.split()' on a line of integers and strings while reading in a text file), and you simply want to check if the elements of the list *can be represented* as integers, you can use:

```
all(i.isdigit() for i in myList)
```

**For example:**

```
>>> myList=['1', '2', '3', '150', '500', '6']
>>> all(i.isdigit() for i in myList)
True

>>> myList2=['1.5', '2', '3', '150', '500', '6']
>>> all(i.isdigit() for i in myList2)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

See functions

```
def is_int(x):
    if type(x) == int:
        return True
    return


def all_int(a):
    for i in a:
        if not is_int(i):
            return False
    return True
```

Then call

```
all_int(my_list) # returns boolean
```