# Check if all elements of a list are of the same type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

How can I check if the elements of a list are of the same type, without checking individually every element if possible?

For example, I would like to have a function to check that every element of this list is an integer (which is clearly false):

```
x = [1, 2.5, 'a']

def checkIntegers(x):
    # return True if all elements are integers, False otherwise
```

Comment: How could you possibly do it without checking each element? There's no way to know anything about an element you haven't looked at.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- you can short-circuit as soon as you find a bad one.

Comment: Seems that using `all` is the way...

Comment: @mgilson, yes... I thought the OP was requesting a solution that didn't involve iterating at all.

Comment: "All elements are the same type (as each other)" is a different proposition from "all elements are a *given* type (specified outside the sequence)".

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Try using [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) in conjunction with [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
all(isinstance(x, int) for x in lst)
```

You can even check for multiple types with `isinstance` if that is desireable:

```
all(isinstance(x, (int, long)) for x in lst)
```

---

Not that this will pick up inherited classes as well.  e.g.:

```
class MyInt(int):
     pass

print(isinstance(MyInt('3'),int)) #True
```

If you *need* to restrict yourself to just integers, you could use `all(type(x) is int for x in lst)`.  But that is a **VERY** rare scenario.

---

A fun function you could write with this is one which would return the type of the first element in a sequence if all the other elements are the same type:

```
def homogeneous_type(seq):
    iseq = iter(seq)
    first_type = type(next(iseq))
    return first_type if all( (type(x) is first_type) for x in iseq ) else False
```

This will work for any arbitrary iterable, but it will consume "iterators" in the process.

Another fun function in the same vein which returns the set of common bases:

```
import inspect
def common_bases(seq):
    iseq = iter(seq)
    bases = set(inspect.getmro(type(next(iseq))))
    for item in iseq:
        bases = bases.intersection(inspect.getmro(type(item)))
        if not bases:
           break
    return bases
```

---

Comment: Note that `homogeneous_type()` (I guess that's what the function is supposed to be called) errors out for empty iterators.  Moreover, the result depends on the order of the items in the iterable (I guess this is what you mean by "iterator"), which is not what I would expect from a function of this name.  (An example would be `[0, False]` and `[False, 0]`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- I suppose that's a reasonable point.  I think that it's fine to error out on empty iterators (I actually considered that when I wrote the function) ... What should the result be in the case of an empty iterable?  As far as passing a list of `[0, False]` or `[False, 0]`, I *could* fix that by doing `all( type(x) is first_type for x in iseq )`, but it seems to me that the function would be more useful if it checked out OK for subclasses as well.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- Finally, Yes I did mean `iterable`.  For semantics, what term would you use to describe iterables that can be consumed (`iter(...)` or generators) vs iterables which cannot (`list`, `tuple`, ...)?  (And thanks for looking at this critically.  Hopefully it'll make for a better answer :)

Comment: `all()` also has the advantage in that it will short circuit and stop as soon as it encounters a `False` value from the generator expression.

Comment: Based on the question's code example, shouldn't `x` be the list object?

Comment: Just realized that `all` returns `True` for an empty iterable, which is why `homogeneous_type` works for sequences of length 1. Clever!

Answer (score 10):

Using [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), no need to traverse whole list. Just break as soon as object which is not `int` or `long` is found:

```
>>> not any(not isinstance(y,(int,long)) for y in [1,2,3])
True
>>> not any(not isinstance(y,(int,long)) for y in [1,'a',2,3])
False
```

Comment: The logic is much more clean with `all`, but I suppose `not any(not condition ...)` works too.  +1 for your efforts I suppose (and for demonstrating `all`'s counterpart, which is just as useful.)

Comment: @mgilson This occured to me when I saw your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/python-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-the-same-type/13252359#comment18058092_13252333) :), otherwise I was happy with `all()` based solution.

Comment: `all` also short circuits, so there isn't really any difference between this and @mgilson's solution. It's more an exercise in logic...

Comment: Generically speaking, I think what you'd need to do is check if any element is not the same type as the first. i.e. `any(not isinstance(e,type(seq[0])) for e in seq[1:])`

Comment: @martineau -- Assuming that you can slice `seq` of course.  Otherwise you need to use `iter` and `next` -- Which saves you the overhead of making a copy, but that's typically pretty cheap for lists.

Comment: `%timeit all(isinstance(x, basestring) for x in list_w_int_or_str)` actually takes less time than `%timeit not any(not isinstance(x, basestring) for x in list_w_int_or_str)`

Answer (score 5):

Combining some of the answers already given, using a combination of map(), type() and set() provides a imho rather readable answer. Assuming the limitation of not checking for type polymorphisms is ok. Also not the most computationally efficient answer, but it allows to easily check whether all elements are of the same type.

```
# To check whether all elements in a list are integers
set(map(type, [1,2,3])) == {int}
# To check whether all elements are of the same type
len(set(map(type, [1,2,3]))) == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to check if a list is composed of omogeneous elements can be with the groupby function of the itertools module:

```
from itertools import groupby
len(list(groupby(yourlist,lambda i:type(i)))) == 1
```

If th len is different from one it means that it found different kind of types in the list.
This has the problem of running trough the entire sequence.
If you want a lazy version you can write a function for that:

```
def same(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    try:
        first = type(next(iterable))
        return all(isinstance(i,first) for i in iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
```

This function store the type of the first element and stop as soon as it find a different type in one of the elements in the list.

Both of this methods are strongly sensitive to the type, so it will see as different int and float, but this should be as close as you can get to your request

EDIT:

replaced the for cycle with a call to all as suggested by  mgilson

in case of void iterator it returns True to be consistent with the behavior of the bulitin all function

Comment: The first request of the OP is not to check is all the elements were of a specific type, but to check if all the element were of the same type, indipendently from which one was the first. It is a solution to a slightly different problem.

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri -- but you can still do a short circuiting version in 3 lines.  `a=iter(obj);t=type(next(a));all(isinstance(x,t) for x in a)`. It's even easier for a list which is what the question is about -- `t = type(lst[0]); return all(instance(x,t) for x in lst[1:])`.  Not too shabby.

Comment: yes, you can shortcircuit it, but it will not handle void iterators and will raise an exception. It's just a matter of choice, in my case i prefere to handle it instead of raising

Comment: Instead of `lambda i: type(i)`, you can simply use `type`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def checkInt(l):
    return all(isinstance(i, (int, long)) for i in l)

>>> checkInt([1,2,3])
True
>>> checkInt(['a',1,2,3])
False
>>> checkInt([1,2,3,238762384762364892364])
True
```

Comment: `isinstance()` should be preferred over `type()`.

Comment: Which of the two is faster, `isinstance()` or `type()`?

Comment: `isinstance(i,(int,long))` is short. it's not about speed, type() will fail for subclasses of int

Comment: @mgilson yeah, i just noticed also that you beat me to the answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

I like the function by *EnricoGiampieri* ([above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252614/2668831)) but there is a simpler version using `all_equal` from the *"[Itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)"* section of the `itertools` docs:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def all_equal(iterable):
    "Returns True if all the elements are equal to each other"
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

All of these recipes are [packaged](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/recipes.html) in  `more_itertools`:

> Substantially all of these recipes and many, many others can be installed from the more-itertools project found on the Python Package Index:
>
> `pip install more-itertools`
>
> The extended tools offer the same high performance as the underlying toolset. The superior memory performance is kept by processing elements one at a time rather than bringing the whole iterable into memory all at once. Code volume is kept small by linking the tools together in a functional style which helps eliminate temporary variables. High speed is retained by preferring “vectorized” building blocks over the use of for-loops and generators which incur interpreter overhead.

```py
from more_itertools import all_equal

all_equal(map(type, iterable))
```

or with `isinstance` and a known type `int` (as per the original question)

```py
all_equal(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), iterable))
```

These two ways are more concise than Enrico's suggestion and handle 'void iterators' (e.g. `range(0)`) just as Enrico's function does.

```py
all_equal(map(type, range(0))) # True
all_equal(map(type, range(1))) # True
all_equal(map(type, range(2))) # True

all_equal(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), range(0))) # True
all_equal(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), range(1))) # True
all_equal(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), range(2))) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `type()` if you want to exclude subclasses. See [the difference between `isinstance()` and `type()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python):

```
>>> not any(not type(y) is int for y in [1, 2, 3])
True
>>> not any(not type(y) == int for y in [1, 'a', 2.3])
False
```

Although you may not want to, because this will be more fragile. If y changes its type to a subclass of int, this code will break, whereas `isinstance()` will still work.

It's OK to use `is` because there is only one `<type 'int'>` in memory, so they should return the same identity if they are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer you use this method, where you iterate through each item in the list and check if they are all same data type, if Yes, returns True else, False.

```
def checkIntegers(x):
    # return True if all elements are integers, False otherwise
    return all(isinstance(i, type(x[0])) for i in x[1:])

x = [1, 2.5, 'a']
checkIntegers(x)

False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise function regarding this, currently it checks (in a `list`) if all items are **integer** or if all items are **string**, or if **mixed data type**.

```
def check_item_dtype_in_list(item_range):
    if all(map(lambda x: str(x).isdigit(), item_range)):
        item_range = list(map(int, item_range))
        print('all are integer')
        print(item_range)
        return 
    elif all(isinstance(item, str) for item in item_range):
        print('all are string')
        print(item_range)
        return 
    elif any(map(lambda x: str(x), item_range)):
        print('mixed dtype')
        print(item_range)
        return
```

```
check_item_dtype_in_list(['2', 2, 3])
check_item_dtype_in_list(["2", 2, 'Two'])
check_item_dtype_in_list(['Two', 'Two', 'Two'])
check_item_dtype_in_list([2, 2., 'Two'])
```

```
all are integer
[2, 2, 3]
mixed dtype
['2', 2, 'Two']
all are string
['Two', 'Two', 'Two']
mixed dtype
[2, 2.0, 'Two']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    def c(x):
         for i in x:
             if isinstance(i,str):
                   return False
             if isinstance(i,float):
                   return False

          return True
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use map for a case like this:

```
from types import IntType
In [21]: map((lambda x: isinstance(x, IntType)), x)
   Out[21]: [True, False, False]
```