# How to check if all items in list are string

Tags: python

If I have a list in python, is there a function to tell me if all the items in the list are strings?

For Example:
`["one", "two", 3]` would return `False`, and `["one", "two", "three"]` would return `True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python check if all elements of a list are the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/python-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-the-same-type)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use `all()` and check for types with `isinstance()`.

```
>>> l = ["one", "two", 3]
>>> all(isinstance(item, str) for item in l)
False
>>> l = ["one", "two", '3']
>>> all(isinstance(item, str) for item in l)
True
```

Comment: One more question, is there a way to check if  no numerical strings are in a list. For example: ["one", "two", "3"] would return false

Comment: @TekhenyGhemor - `isinstance(item, str) and not item.lstrip('-').isdigit()` for zero or positive integers. It gets more involved if you want to check for floats, complex numbers, etc.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman - Do you mean getting rid of the `all()` and the generator expression (not a list comprehension) and creating a traditional `for..else` loop? Or do you mean breaking up the current code into multiple lines? I don't see how either of those would help. This is already concise, clear, and canonical.

Answer (score 1):

Answering @TekhenyGhemor's follow-up question: is there a way to check if no numerical strings are in a list. For example: ["one", "two", "3"] would return false

Yes.  You can convert the string to a number and make sure that it raises an exception:

```
def isfloatstr(x):
    try: 
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def valid_list(L):
    return all((isinstance(el, str) and not isfloatstr(el)) for el in L)
```

Checking:

```
>>> valid_list(["one", "two", "3"])
False

>>> valid_list(["one", "two", "3a"])
True

>>> valid_list(["one", "two", 0])
False
```

In [5]: valid_list(["one", "two", "three"])
Out[5]: True

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is using the `map()` function:

```
>>> all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), ['one', 'two', 3]))
False
>>> all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), ['one', 'two', 'three']))
True
```