# Python: check for data type in list

Tags: python, search, types, find

Is there a way to check if an instance of a specific data type is present in a list / dictionary, *without explicitly checking every element / key?*

I suspect the answer is no. If it does exist, though, I imagine it would be similar to the way you can use the `in` operator to search for specific elements / keys, like this:

```
3 in [1, 2, 3] # => True
```

except you'd be checking for an instance of a data type rather than a some specific value, like this:

```
int in [1,"a", 3.4] # => True
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, you *have* to check every element of the list, or keep track of the types in and out of your list yourself. Python `list` objects have no knowledge of the types of the objects it contains. Note, the `in` operator *checks every element*.

Comment: Check this out, almost similar question with interesting answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/python-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-the-same-type

Comment: and the answer is no to your first question. It is not possible without iterating over the elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well `in` is actually syntactic sugar for `__contains__`, which [**does** iterate](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c310233b1d64/Objects/listobject.c#l393) over the contents of the list.

If you would like to use `in` to check for types instead; you could implement your own data structure (subclassing `list`) and override `__contains__` to check for types:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __contains__(self, typ):
        for val in self:
            if isinstance(val, typ):
                return True
        return False

x = MyList([1, 2, 'a', 3])

print float in x # False
print str in x   # True
```

You could also take advantage of the [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
def __contains__(self, typ):
    return any(isinstance(val, typ) for val in self)

print int in MyList([1, "a", 3.4]) # True
print int in MyList(["a", 3.4])    # False
```

As for whether this is doable without checking every element - no, it's not. In the worst case scenario, you do end up checking every element.

Comment: The custom class can contain a set of types, updated each insert/delete... so the check can be fast... if we are going the custom class way :-)

Comment: Actually a counter for each data type would work better. The `__contains__` can also check if the argument's `type` is `type`... I see a new UserTypeList being born ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use **isinstance(element, type)**.

I made a function:

```
def checkType(a_list):
    for element in a_list:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            print("It's an Integer")
        if isinstance(element, str):
            print("It's an string")
        if isinstance(element, float):
            print("It's an floating number")

numbers = [1, 2, 3]
checkType(numbers)
```

This outputs:

```
It's an Integer
It's an Integer
It's an Integer
```

Comment: As a side note, if the element is equal to a boolean value (`True` or `False`), both `isinstance(element, bool)` and `isinstance(element, int)` evaluates to True.  So if you want to distinguish between the these two data types in a list, you will have to add [additional conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48025345/17627866)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this will be your input list and you can check on iterating on it and I got pass two times

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 6, '8', 9, 8]
for i in a:
    if i in [2, 8] and type(i) == int:
        print('pass')
```