# How can I select only integers from list and not booleans?

Tags: python

I have a code to get only integers from a list:

```
list = [i for i in list if isinstance(i, int)]
```

However, if the list is `[True, 19, 19.5, False]`, it will return `[True, 19, False].` I need it to return only `[19]`, not the `True` and `False`. How do I do that?

Comment: In python `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`. `bool` is subclass of `int`. To check if value is just `int` you need to use either `type(i) is int` or add second condition `not isinstance(i, bool)`

Comment: @Olvin That might be a confusing way to put it since `True is not 1 and False is not 0`. It'd be clearer to just say that `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True == 1 and False == 0`.

Comment: Also, best not to name variables `list` as that's a built-in type.

Comment: @wjandrea, but `hash(True) == hash(1)`

Comment: @Olvin So? `hash(1.0) == hash(1)`

Comment: Related: [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](/q/152580/4518341) (covers `isinstance(x, <type>)` vs `type(x) is <type>`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to distinguish bool from int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025345/python-how-to-distinguish-bool-from-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `True/False` values are also the instances of `int` in Python, so you can add one more condition to check if the value is not an instance of `bool`:

```py
>>> lst = [True, 19, 19.5, False]
>>> [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool)]
[19]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `type` comparison instead:

```
_list = [i for i in _list if type(i) is int]
```

This is due to the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, thus a boolean value is an instance of `int` at all effects.
Indeed, inspecting the class [hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(bool)
(bool, int, object)
>>> inspect.getmro(float)
(float, object)
>>> inspect.getmro(int)
(int, object)
```

Side note: avoid using `list` as the variable name since it's the Python builtin name for the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) type.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a subclass of `int`, therefore `True` is an instance of `int`.

- `False` equal to `0`
- `True` equal to `1`

you can use another check or `if type(i) is int`