# python: Check if all the elements in the list are only numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, integer

I want to check if all the elements in a list are only numbers. In string we can easily do it using `isdigit()` function but how can we do it in a list?
For ex: if we enter a list,

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

it will return true.
and

```
l2=["abc","xyz","pqr"]
```

will return false.

Comment: Use the `isinstance()` function.

Comment: are the entries of your list `str`ings (where `isdigit` could be applied) or `int`egers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements of a list are of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-of-the-same-type)

Comment: @KentShikama The answers there use `isdigit()` to allow strings that look like integers, but this question seems to be looking for actual integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `type` function in conjunction with an `all` to gather the results.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = ["abc", "xyz", "pqr"]

print(all(type(e) in (int, float) for e in l1))
print(all(type(e) in (int, float) for e in l2))
```

Results in:

```
True
False
```