# How do I check that Variable has type List[str]?

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror, valueerror

```
x = ['string1','string1','string1']
```

How do I check that `x` has type `List[str]`?

```
if type(x) != List[str]:
   raise ValueError("x should be list of str")
```

This if condition returns `True` and `raise Error` but should not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements of a list are of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-of-the-same-type)

Comment: Do you want to check this statically or at runtime?

Comment: I think this question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-of-the-same-type

Comment: Well, `type(x)` returs `list` and not `List[str]`

Comment: I thought there was some solution without going through all the values in the list

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```py
if not (isinstance(x, list) and all(isinstance(item, str) for item in x)):
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Well, I thought there was some solution without going through all the values in the list

Comment: No, because `list` doesn't enforce that it's members are of one specific type. You could create a custom type that does that, though