# Is there a way to check each passed argument's type in Python?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Let's say I have a function that takes any number of arguments. Is there a way, except loops, to check if each of those arguments is a list?

```
def func(*args):
    # check if all args are lists
```

I was trying `any()` and `all()` methods, but can't figure out if there is a way to use `isinstance()` and `type()` with them.

Comment: Dup of [Check if all elements of a list are of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 5):

Sure thing:

```
all_lists = all(isinstance(arg, list) for arg in args)
```

Answer (score 0):

`all(isinstance(arg, list) for arg in args)`

Of course, there's a loop hidden in the generator expression; at the end of the day, there has to be some kind of loop..

Comment: BTW, depending on your purpose, it might be more relevant to ask "are they all `Iterable`" (can be used in a `for` loop) or "are they each a `Sequence`" (can be used with `[i]`) or similar

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer above:

```
all_lists = all(isinstance(arg, list) for arg in args)
```

But note you can also do type hints in the newer versions of Python:

```
def func(*args:list):
    # check if all args are lists
```

and you get some type checking from tools like `Mypy`

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants of this question:

1. How to determine the type of an object?
2. How to get the class of an object?
3. How to check the type of an instance?
4. How to check the class of an instance?

In Python, the built-in functions type() and isinstance() help you determine the type of an object.

1. type(object) – Returns a string representation of the object’s type.
2. isinstance(object, class) – Returns a Boolean True if the object is
   an instance of the class, and False otherwise.

reference : [Determining the type of an object](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-determine-the-type-of-an-object-in-python/#type_vs_isinstance)

also check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-isinstance-python/) for more details.

Comment: Indeed; in many cases, the question is also not so much "is it a list" but "is it iterable" (can be used in a `for` loop) or "is it a sequence" (can be used with `[i]`)